# React Js navigation, re-render previous component in new routed page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, navigation

Soo, im new on react js framework. im trying to make an navigation link. but when it clicked, it re-render the previous component . codes below

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Card, Button , ListGroup }  from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter,Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Mappage from '../mapPage';
import Home from '../home';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
class FloorOne extends Component {
    state = { 
     }  
    render() { 
    //   const floors = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
        return (
           <BrowserRouter>
            <div className='cardContainer'>
            <ListGroup as ="ul" className='floorCard'>
         
                <ListGroup.Item as ="li">
            
                   <Link to="/mapPage"> link to map</Link>
               
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <ListGroup.Item as ="li">
                    <Link to="/home"> buttom home</Link>
                </ListGroup.Item>
                <Routes >
                          <Route path="/mapPage" element={ <Mappage/>}/>
                          <Route path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
                </Routes>
              </ListGroup>
            </div>
             </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
export default FloorOne;
```

i use route and routes and link it  to a component as i thought its a "page". but the previous component still renderd on the page other page that i navigate (either mappage or hompage)

this is homepage

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

function Home() {
    return <div>
       <h1>this is homepage</h1>
    </div>
    ;
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: oh ya, this is my first question in s/o. this is also a learning project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, React is a library, not a framework.
And your `Link` components always should be in the children of `Routes` component. Try using `Link` in `Mappage` or `home`. There it should work

Your FloorOne Component should be like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter,Routes } from 'react-router-dom'
import Mappage from '../mapPage';
import Home from '../home';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class FloorOne extends Component {
    state = { }  
    render() { 
    //   const floors = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
        return (
           <BrowserRouter>
              <Routes >
                 <Route path="/mapPage" element={<Mappage />}/>
                 <Route path="/home" element={<Home />}/>
              </Routes>
           </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}
```

Your Home Component can be like this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, Button , ListGroup }  from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'


function Home() {
    return (
.     <div>
        <ListGroup as="ul" className='floorCard'>       
           <ListGroup.Item as="li">        
               <Link to="/mapPage"> link to map</Link>             
           </ListGroup.Item>
           <ListGroup.Item as="li">
               <Link to="/home"> buttom home</Link>
           </ListGroup.Item>              
        </ListGroup>       
      </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: thankyou to correct me about react library. and, how do you actually put link component inside children of routes? isnt routes children supposed to be just route component ?

Comment: I meant about the props of element attribute inside `Routes` which are `Home` and `Mappage`. They will be rendered by `react-router-dom` and thus the `Link` will be also available in them

Answer (score 0):

Use exact in your Route

```
    <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/mapPage" element={ <Mappage/>}/>
        <Route exact path="/home" element={<Home/>}/>
   </Routes>
```

Comment: `exact` is no longer required in latest react-router dom

Comment: Hmm, interesting, should I quit using the old version of react-router-dom? Are there any major changes in the new version?

Comment: If you are currenlty in v5, then there are really massive changes waiting. Many components are renamed like from `Redirect` to `Navigate` and some behaviours are also updated like `activeStyle`

Comment: hai, thank you guys to help me out. I tried to use exact path= in route component, but it still doesnt work . any idea ? :)